# How do I start an application fullscreen without loading IceWM desktop environment?

Tags: arm, icewm

### Setup

- ARM computer FriendlyARM mini210s
- Debian Linux 3.0.8 (armv7l) + IceWM

### How can I start an application alone without the desktop environment?

For the sake of prototyping I want to start Chromium alone in fullscreen.

In `/usr/share/xsessions/` I found 2 files:

```
root@FriendlyARM:~# ls -al /usr/share/xsessions/

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  238 Feb 18  2013 IceWM.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  204 Feb 18  2013 icewm-session.desktop
```

#### root@FriendlyARM:~# more /usr/share/xsessions/IceWM.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
# The names/descriptions should really be better
Name=IceWM
Comment=This is the window manager IceWM
Comment[de]=Dies ist der Fenstermanager IceWM
Exec=/usr/bin/icewm-session
Icon=icewm.xpm
Type=Application
```

#### root@FriendlyARM:~# more /usr/share/xsessions/icewm-session.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=icewm
Name[en_US]=icewm
Comment=Simple and fast window manger
Terminal=false
Exec=icewm-session
TryExec=icewm-session

[Window Manager]
SessionManaged=true
```

Assuming that this is the right way to do it,

### How do I tweak these files to achieve my objective?

Comment: [Similar issue](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/how-can-i-boot-directly-into-google-chrome-web-browser). Amounts to adding chromium to `.xinitrc` after configuring `gdm` to automatically login.

Comment: Not 100% but with Chrome I think you need to start it with `--kiosk` to get it to start fullscreened.

Answer (score 0):

2 pages helped me a great deal

[IceWM Basic Configuration](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=5450)

[IceWM on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IceWM)

I will update this post with the details of my findings.

- I have installed IceWM lite (lighter and without a taskbar at the bottom)

  ```
  apt-get install icewm-lite
  ```